# Push Pop cell array Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, cell

I want to delete some cell(s) from cell array in *Matalb* on run time in nested *for-loops*, so that I want permanently delete cell and on next iteration, It will not consider that cell infect its next cell as its place, How I can perform this in *Matlab*, or any other suggestions to avoid cell array in this case. My cell array `M` contains objects information and `P` is the position values.

**My Code:**

```
for ii=1:1000
    for jj=1:20
        M{jj}=P{jj}(ii,:);
        if (P{jj}(ii,:) ~= 0)
            %here I want to delete M(jj) or M{jj} and also P(jj) or P{jj}
            % My try  M(jj) = []; M=  M(~cellfun('isempty',M));
            %but it gives error when the next iteration starts.
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think it won't reach inside the conditional statement `if (M{jj} == 0 )` because the way you are assigning `M{jj}` before the conditional statements.

Comment: That was just an example, pls check edited Code, I want to delete some `jj` like `jj=2` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `while` instead of `for` for this special case -

```
ii=1;
jj=1;

jj_limit = 20;
while ii<=1000
    while jj<=jj_limit
        M{jj}=P{jj}(ii,:);
        if (P{jj}(ii,:) ~= 0)
            P(jj)=[];
            M(jj)=[];
            jj_limit = jj_limit-1;
            continue;
        end
        jj = jj+1;
    end
    ii = ii+1;
end
```

Comment: But I want to increment step as `for ii=1:dt:1000`.

Comment: So just replace `ii = ii+1;`  with `ii=ii+dt;`

Comment: OK, I have tried this but `while` doesn't help for me in my case. I don't know why, but I think it is required by for loop and also I want to slice my operations in order to use `parfor` loop later.

Comment: It might be because of the way you have your data. On the `parfor`, not sure if it can handle conditional statements.

Comment: pls make me scenario for the `for loop`. is it any possibility ?

Comment: Want to use `parfor` and at the sametime delete elements from it? Sounds like a big ask really.

Comment: Isn't possible ? What a solution if simple `for`